# Playing audio file from fulfillment in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Can't get the audio link (to a mp3 file on google drive) to play.

It works excellent to play an explicit .ogg file but not a link to a file on google drive

This works:

```
agent.add("<speak><audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/transportation/ship_bell.ogg\"> <desc>Ljudfil</desc> Fel)</audio></speak>")
```

This does not:

```
agent.add("<speak><audio src=\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gHtUWgwKCHq3nygNZIoZzXqki5K0mjB2/view\"> <desc>Ljudfil</desc> Fel)</audio></speak>")
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is this for the Google Assistant?